# JavaScript, concatenate array-valued property values in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

When I call an ajax POST request, I get back a JSON array with any validation errors. Here is an example of the response:

```
{
    password: [
        "The password confirmation does not match"
    ], 
    username: [
        "A username is required", 
        "Your username must be at least 5 characters long."
    ]
}
```

How can I minify this to get an array of just the error messages? My ultimate goal is to push each of the messages into a div. What I can do is iterate through each of the messages in the password, then the username, then the email etc... But I wanted to see if there are any alternative ways or better ways of doing this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop over all of the keys in the response ("password" and "username" in your example) using `Object.keys` and combine their contents into a single output array. Something like:

```js
var data = {
  password: [
    "The password confirmation does not match"
  ],
  username: [
    "A username is required",
    "Your username must be at least 5 characters long."
  ]
};

var joined = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(dest, key) {
  return dest.concat(data[key]);
}, []);

document.getElementById('r').textContent = JSON.stringify(joined);
```

```html
<pre id=r></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just sending an array of error messages.Iterate through the array and put them in your div.

```
{
    errorMsgs: [
        "The password confirmation does not match",
         "A username is required", 
        "Your username must be at least 5 characters long."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Probably, the OP doesn't want to or can't change the format of the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

```
[].concat.apply([], Object.keys(json) . map(function(key) { return json[key]; }));
```

How this works:

`concat` takes a list of arguments and concatenates them altogether. We need to arrange to pass it the arrays which are the values of the properties such as `password`. To do that, we use `apply` to allow us to pass in all the arguments it expects as an array. To create this array, we **map** the keys of the object to their values.

In ES6, you could write this more simply as

```
[].concat(...Object.keys(json) . map(key => json[key]));
```